# PHP Remove Quotes from JSON String of CURL Response

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

```
 //...snip..
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

The response of a php curl request is showing as

> "{\"result\":\"success\",\"entry\":\"22\",\"confirm\":\"yes\"}"

However, the output should not have `\` in front of the quotes. 
How do I remove those quotes and return as proper **JSON**

```
{
"result":"success",
"entry":"22",
"confirm":"yes"
}
```

Few options I tried are `return print_r($result)`. This is returning as expected, but I think this is not proper way.

PHP version - 5.6.16

Answer (score 2):

Your output is correct and you have valid json; which is a string.

All you have to do, is decode it:

```
$s = "{\"result\":\"success\",\"entry\":\"22\",\"confirm\":\"yes\"}";

var_dump(json_decode($s));
```

[An example](https://eval.in/620394).

Comment: But `json_decode` removes keys like result, entry, confirm.

Comment: @blakcaps What do you mean, have you checked the example? It returns an object with the keys `result`, `entry`, etc.

Comment: @blakcaps yes jeroen is right .. it returns an object with keys only .. please check.

Comment: I am trying to return the `$result` from a method. How can I use `var_dump` for method return

Comment: @blakcaps The `var_dump()` was just to show the results, if you need an object (or array...), just return the result of `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes) to remove slashes from the JSON String then decode the JSON String using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Like this,

```
$json_string="{\"result\":\"success\",\"entry\":\"22\",\"confirm\":\"yes\"}";
$json_string=stripslashes($json_string);
$json_array=json_decode($json_string,true);
print_r($json_array);
```

---

Above method just remove the slashes from the string and uses **json_decode()** to decode the JSON String.

But you can also decode the string directly with the slashes. (Thanks to @jeroen) 
Like this,

```
$json_string="{\"result\":\"success\",\"entry\":\"22\",\"confirm\":\"yes\"}";
$json_array=json_decode($json_string,true);
print_r($json_array);
```

---

Second parameter in **json_decode()** denotes you want to parse the JSON String in array instead of object which is default behavior.

Comment: There is no need to use `stripslashes()`, you can decode this directly.

Comment: Its true, stripslashes not required. If you add stripslashes json string will break

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following header option in your curl, will return json object:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Because default accept type is Text/Plain so it will return you parsed sting. By setting above header you will receive json object.